# Cron job per second is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Cron job per second is not working in wordpress.
Here is my code :

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'new_interval');
function new_interval($interval) {
    $interval['everysecond'] = array('interval' => 1, 'display' => 'Once Second');
    return $interval;
}



add_action( 'wp_footer', 'InitiateMyCronTEST' );
function InitiateMyCronTEST() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('MyCronActionSecondTEST')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'everysecond', 'MyCronActionSecondTEST');
    }
}

add_action('MyCronActionSecondTEST','run_cron_for_quiz_test');
function run_cron_for_quiz_test()
{
    error_log("I am in TEST cron job at !".current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ), 0);
}
```

Please let me know where is the bug / what need to fix ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to get a cronjob of twicer per hour like at a bigger interval. I think one second is a bit too much.

Comment: Also why are you hooking it to the footer?

Comment: Should I put it in head ?

Comment: I think if you hook it normally it will do just fine.

Comment: Also are you using some kind of special third party plugin for your cronjobs?

Answer (score 1):

Found a little bit of code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220949/how-to-insert-post-with-cron-job-in-wordpress) question.
Try this and see if it works.

Someone commented: "Don't forget WordPress cron "mechanism" is still "non-automatic" emulator. If visitors (peoples, search engines, etc) are visiting your website every minutes - cron will work. If visitors don't "touch" your website - cron will not work."

So it might not even work like a proper cronjob in the background. Good luck!

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'new_interval');

function new_interval($interval) {
    $interval['everyminute'] = array('interval' => 60, 'display' => 'Once every minute');

    return $interval;
}

function InitiateMyCron() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('MyCronEvent')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'everyminute', 'MyCronAction');
    }
}

function MyCronAction() {
    error_log("I am in TEST cron job at !".current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for the support for me. But as per your given code the cron job will run in every minute. But I want to run a cron job per second.

Comment: I found [another question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88430/how-do-i-schedule-cron-in-wordpress-for-each-second) on the WP stack exchange site. They are also saying running a cronjob each second is not good for the site and will not work most of the time since you need at least one visitor per second for it to execute. Consider using a bigger interval or improving your script because it will not be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the support for me.